# How to get absolute path of directory of a file?

Tags: java, file-io

How can I get an absolute path of a directory containing a file specified:

```
// current dir is "/home/me/dev"
File file = new File("./target/test.txt");
assert absolute(file).equals("/home/me/dev/target");
```

It's Java 6.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You mean the [methods in the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)?

```
File file = new File("./target/test.txt");
String dirPath = file.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
assert dirPath.equals("/home/me/dev/target");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
assert file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().equals("/home/me/dev/target");
```