# I keep getting java.io.FileNotFoundException with my zip extractor

Tags: java, file, exception

Could anybody help me with my java zip extractor as stated in the title I keep getting java.io.FileNotFoundException on the folders with files in them

```
public void UnZip() {
    try {
        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
        int byteRead;

        BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile)));
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String filename = entry.getName();
            File newfile = new File(Deobf2 + File.separator + filename);

            System.out.println("file unzip : " + newfile.getAbsoluteFile());

            new File(newfile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

            int len;
            while ((len = zin.read(data)) > 0) {
                fos.write(data, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();
            entry = zin.getNextEntry();
        }
        zin.closeEntry();
        zin.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

error log
http://pastebin.com/crMKaa37

values

```
static String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
public static File Deobf = new File(tempDir + "Deobf");
public static String Deobf2 = Deobf.toString();
```

entire code paste
http://pastebin.com/1vTfABR1

Comment: Can you post the error and perhaps the values of `Deobf2` & `filename` at the point of failure

Comment: please check whether your file really exists or not!

Comment: what are you trying to do here String Deobf2 = Deobf.toString();

Comment: Turn the Deobf file variable into a string

Comment: @Ry_dog101 are you trying to get the filename?

Comment: The location of the Deobf temp file as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have copy pasted same code and it is working fine. I think u dont have administrator permission on C drive. login As Administrator and run . it will work. 
Access Denied Exception will come when u don have administrator level of permission on C drive.

Comment: Ok running my IDE as administrator fixed part of the error now I'm getting this error http://pastebin.com/g7rXaQdt

Comment: Could u pls try to unzip another zip file. i think some prob with that zip.

Comment: Zip files with things in them that this program will be used for give the same sort of error http://pastebin.com/yEu2uGq8

Comment: this may not be the answer but try once. As m not getting error. please commnet this line in Main.java  // static String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"); and change this line also like this   public static File Deobf = new File( "Deobf");. then unzipped files will be placed in ur project folder. under "Deobf" folder..

Comment: ok then do one thing send me that zip file to my mail i will run and check it ..gangulanarendar@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Your doing

```
String Deobf2 = Deobf.toString();//this does not give the location of the file
```

use

```
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

in your case `Deobf.getAbsolutePath();`

instead. Check http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/
if you want to get the path only till the parent directory check this [How to get absolute path of directory of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6116128/2006839)

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed changed some code
for anyone whos wants a copy of the working zip extraction code here you go http://pastebin.com/bXL8pUSg
The variable Deobf2 in the output of the zip